Forcing repeated grid iterations
We have a requirement to enter a value in a control (Repeating Grid Rows), then use that number to create the same number of Repeated Grid rows/iterations.
Furthermore, if that control number is adjusted up/down, then the Repeated Grid rows/iterations need to automatically adjust (even if that means deleting a row with data in it).
I can see how to force a maximum number of rows in the grid, but I don't understand how to automatically create/delete rows.
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/ca9225d389f1bd3256275665e9ea2925ff09bef9?form-version=1

You can do this by adding code similar to the following in the source of your form. In this example, the control with the number is children-count, and the repeated grid is named children.
For now, you'll need to use the action syntax in the form's source, but there is a Request for Enhancement #1658 to add a UI for this.
<fr:listener version="2018.2" events="value-changed" controls="children-count"
             actions="update-rows"/>
<fr:action version="2018.2" name="update-rows">
    <fr:data-iterate ref="1 to xs:integer(//children-count - count(//children-iteration))">
       <fr:repeat-add-iteration repeat="children" at="end"/>
    </fr:data-iterate>
    <fr:data-iterate ref="1 to xs:integer(count(//children-iteration) - //children-count)">
       <fr:repeat-remove-iteration repeat="children" at="end"/>
    </fr:data-iterate>
</fr:action>

The animation below shows what happens if we only add row automatically, but don't remove them, and instead show a validation error when the specified number of children doesn't match the number of rows in the repeated grid.


That worked perfect thanks..

We now need to add a popup message if the number of rows is reduced to warn the user that they may lose some data.
I've not ben very successful at this bit either??
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/ca9225d389f1bd3256275665e9ea2925ff09bef9

@PeteAtkin Displaying a pop-up can be quite complex. When should the pop-up appear? When the user tabs out of the field? And what happens if the user doesn’t confirm the change? Should the previous value in the field be restored?

@PeteAtkin Instead of using a pop-up, I would remove the code that eliminates iterations when the number of children exceeds the number of iterations. I would then add a constraint requiring the number of children to match the number of iterations. If this condition is not met, an alert should notify users that they need to manually adjust the number of children in the repeated grid to match the number of iterations. Would that make sense?

Ideally se want a warning before the rows are auto deleted, so a popup with Yes/No option works for us.
But I'm having issues calling an alert-dialog from within the fr:action </fr:action> tags.

The user will select the number of rows. If this number is greater that the current rows, then the system should go ahead and add the rows. If the number of rows requested is smaller than the current number of rows, then a popup should be issued asking whether the user wants to delete these rows:

NO: then there is no action (other than making the requested number of rows the same as the current row number).
YES: then the rows are deleted along with their data.

PeteA
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/d1c3e5f0eb6fa7232da253287707f364b331d529

@PeteAtkin The action syntax doesn't directly support displaying a dialog. I've included an animated image showing what happens when we use a validation error instead of automatically deleting iterations. While this is subjective, I'm not convinced that using a dialog—something that isn't easily achievable with the action syntax—would be an improvement. You can also access this form at: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/c13279569254e27068fdc1af2efc1368a759b975.

Thanks Alex,
As it happens, we were discussing exactly the same solution early this afternoon. Great minds and all that!!!!
PeteA

@PeteAtkin Excellent! And of course, feel free to let me know if you encounter any issues implementing that in your actual form.
